# Is it possible to disable or hide the digital zoom controls in the Camera app on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, camera

I don't think I have ever used the digital zoom feature in the Camera app. The controls are just in the way when you wan't to focus something in that part of the image. So, if possible, I want to hide them. I'm not afraid to jailbreak my phone if that is what i takes. Any answer appreciated.

I have an iPhone 3GS.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no officially supported method of disabling the digital zoom feature. One way around it that I use when I (rarely) need to focus on the lower screen portion, is to focus on the subject, then move the camera's view to the preferred state. The camera will preserve this focus state long enough for a picture.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for a *developer* to hide them when displaying the camera interface. But there's no way for a user to turn that control off in Apple's "Camera" app.

Answer (score 0):

Simply instal a different camera app that's more focused (see what I did there) on experienced photographers. [ProCam](http://www.procamapp.com), for example, has an option not only to disable digital zoom, but also tells the truth about how the two lenses on the 7 Plus work, by providing direct control over which lens is active, rather than hiding the (possible, but not guaranteed) switch at 2x "zoom".